# Angular2 Ng2 file Upload CORS issues

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I am new to try `angular2`. I have installed angular2 file upload. I copied all the code from the tutorial right [here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/)

I copy exactly what the developer write there. But I get issues like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/citizen/upload.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response
>   is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I have my `CORS` filter like this in my `SpringBoot`

```
@Component
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {
     @Override
     public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept, enctype");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

It was still ok before I add that angular2 file upload code. How to resolve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a cross origin request happens, it first sends a `HTTP option` to check whether server allows cross origin requests. If you are using Spring security, check whether you are allowing, `HTTP Option` to go without validation. If it's there add a filter like this

```
 protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia, Authorization");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("access-control-expose-headers", "Authorization");

    if (!"OPTIONS".equals(httpServletRequest.getMethod())) {
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: first thing first i add your code. but it still the same error. i just add below my code (in my question) is still doesnt work. i dont get it the allow credential stuff

Comment: You need to set permit all for `HTTP Option` in websecurity config. You should get a `200 OK` for the `HTTP Option` sending from your angular app.

Comment: Sorry, I don't  have a code. But you just have to add this permission before adding your `SimpleCorsFilter`. Add `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()` before adding you filter.